# How to handle a node.js casterror?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following post call:

```
.post(function(req, res) {
  member.findById(req.params.member_id, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
      return (err);

    new_address = {
      street1 : req.body.street1,
      street2 : req.body.street2,
      City : req.body.City,
      State : req.body.State,
      Zip : req.body.Zip,
      Lat : req.body.Lat,
      Lng : req.body.Lng
    };

    if(result.address === undefined){
      result.address.push(new_address);
    }
    else{
      result.address = [new_address];
    }

    result.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
          return res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Address created!!!' });
    });

  });

});
```

For some reason while attempting the `result.save()` call, I receive this error:

```
{
    "message": "Cast to undefined failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"address\"",
    "name": "CastError",
    "value": [
        {
            "address_type": "Home",
            "street1": "2018 Elliot St",
            "City": "Alexandria",
            "State": "LA",
            "Zip": 71301,
            "Lat": 12,
            "Lng": 32
        }
    ],
    "path": "address"
}
```

my Address schema is a child of Member Schema and looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema

var AddressSchema = Schema({
  Address_type : String,
  street1 : String,
  street2 : String,
  City : String,
  State : String,
  Zip : Number,
  Lat : Number,
  Lng : Number
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Address', AddressSchema);
```

Here is the member schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema

var Address = require('./address');
var Award = require('./award');

var MemberSchema = Schema({
  FName : String,
  LName : String,
  address: [Address],
  phone : {
    type : String,
    number : String
  },
  email: String,
  gender: String,
  DOB: Date,
  rank : {
    level : String,
    updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  },
  Awards : {
    personal : Boolean,
    award : [Award],
    granted: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Member', MemberSchema);
```

I am struggling with this here. If anyone can see why I'm getting this error, i would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks much

Comment: Can you post the member schema?

Comment: Does the same thing happen with Awards? I haven't seen schemas used this way. Not saying it's necessarily wrong, but if `Awards.award.push` also does not work we might be onto something.

Comment: This is my first attempt.  I was going to Awards when Address was working.  I'll go ahead and try it while I hope wisdom arrives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you're trying to use a Model (`Address`) when defining your embedded schema in your `MemberSchema`. You're supposed to use a **Schema** when defining [embedded docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), not models.

```
var Address = require('./address');
```

That is a Model, as per your export statement in the related file. Either export the schema, or better, you can access the schema from the model like this: `Address.schema`

So change this line in your `MemberSchema` definition

```
address: [Address],
```

to this

```
address: [Address.schema],
```

And anywhere else you're using it like that change there as well, like `award : [Award.schema],`

Comment: Oh my freakin lord, I have been killing myself on this.  It's nowhere in any of the documentation.  This is awesome.  Thank you.